# Subset vector: remove one element, based on value rather than position

Tags: r, vector, subset

```
library(tidyverse)
```

view first 15 records in starwars dataset

```
head(starwars, 15)
```

remove the 10th record ("Obi-Wan Kenobi"), based on position in the vector
"Obi-Wan Kenobi" is in the 10th position

```
starwarsNames <- unique(starwars$name)[-10]
```

remove the 10th record ("Obi-Wan Kenobi"), based on value in the vector
I see Error in -"Obi-Wan Kenobi" : invalid argument to unary operator when I attempt the following:

```
starwarsNames <- unique(starwars$name)[-"Obi-Wan Kenobi"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setdiff`

```
setdiff(unique(starwars$name), "Obi-Wan Kenobi")
```

Or another option is logical

```
un1  <- unique(starwars$name)
un1[un1 != "Obi-Wan Kenobi"]
```